# Apply function rowwise to pandas dataframe while referencing a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3], 'B': [1, 2], 'C': [0, 1], 'D': [1, 0], 'total': [4, 6]})

   A  B  C  D  total
0  2  1  0  1      4
1  3  2  1  0      6
```

I'm trying to perform a rowwise calculation and create a new column with the result. The calculation is to divide each column ABCD by the total, square it, and sum it up rowwise. This should be the result (0 if total is 0):

```py
   A  B  C  D  total  result
0  2  1  0  1      4   0.375
1  3  2  1  0      6   0.389
```

This is what I've tried so far, but it always returns 0:

```py
df['result'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].apply(lambda x: ((x/df['total'])**2).sum(), axis=1)
```

I guess the problem is `df['total']` in the lambda function, because if I replace this by a number it works fine. I don't know how to work around this though. Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of [div](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html), [pow](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pow.html) and [sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) can solve this :

```
df["result"] = df.filter(regex="[^total]").div(df.total, axis=0).pow(2).sum(1)
df

A   B   C   D   total   result
0   2   1   0   1   4   0.375000
1   3   2   1   0   6   0.388889
```

Answer (score 4):

you could do

```
df['result'] = (df.loc[:, "A": 'D'].divide(df.total, axis=0) ** 2).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I am running your code with Pandas 1.0.0. and I get NAN. Could you check?

Comment: my bad, I didn't specify the axis used to compute the sum, thanks for pointing that out